# Change the location of the image in the popup frame

Tags: image, popup, openlayers

I've managed to get the location of the image value [programatically](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup/Framed-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.Framed.imageSrc), but it looks, what in API there is no way to define the location during popup creation, so all popups has the same background, and I would like to alternate it for different popups.

Is it possible to change the location of the image to be used as the popup frame ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found : we should create the popup, and should change the imageSrc after `.createPopup` but before to `.show` it.